# How to make marker move follow the polyline in Leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there simple way to make a marker to move but follow the polyline? I have try using plugins animatedmarker.js from github but doesn't work. Anyone know how to work or know the code but not use the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [MovingMarker](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker) ? It is quite easy to manipulate and it is working pretty well. I remember having problems on zoom with animatedmarkers. MovingMarker behaves correctly when zooming during animation.

Comment: Did your leaflet version is 1.10?I tried using MovingMarker in leaflet v1.10 but doesn't work